# HAL_GetTick has accuracy problems

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I've tried doing my own millisecond timer on stm32f103r6t, I've used timer 2 with interrupt on period elapsed, then I increase the counter by one step. The clock frequency is 64mhz, (APB1&2 are 64Mhz as well), prescaller is at 127 and the period value is set to 500. I tested by toggling a pin on interrupt and I got a 1ms half-period on the oscilloscope (which is expected).
The other test that I did was to compare it with __Hal_get_ticks() and send it to uart. It seems that __Hal_get_ticks() is faster, and their difference keeps increasing with time. I've posted the code bellow, although I do initialize more peripherals, I haven't used them yet.

long milliseconds=0;
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_9);
milliseconds++;
}

```
int main(void)
{
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  stm32_uart2_set_state(1);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);
//  MX_WWDG_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  char string[100]={0};
  int index=0; 
  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
      uint32_t hall_tick=HAL_GetTick();
      sprintf(string,"It:%lu\tHt:%lu\n\r",milliseconds,hall_tick);
      stm32_uart2_send_string(string, strlen(string));
  }
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL16;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCPCLK2_DIV8;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 127; //prescaller is zero-based (0 means clk/1)
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 500;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

EDIT: This is the default init function for the hal counter, interrupt priority by default is 15, I've tried setting it to 0 but the results are the same. I've measured the perio of HAL_get_tick() and its 998us instead of 1ms

```
    _weak HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_InitTick(uint32_t TickPriority)
{
  /* Configure the SysTick to have interrupt in 1ms time basis*/
  if (HAL_SYSTICK_Config(SystemCoreClock / (1000U / uwTickFreq)) > 0U)
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* Configure the SysTick IRQ priority */
  if (TickPriority < (1UL << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS))
  {
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, TickPriority, 0U);
    uwTickPrio = TickPriority;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* Return function status */
  return HAL_OK;
```

}

Comment: I remember years ago reporting an off-by-one in the systick setup code to ST, but I think they fixed it.  The version of the library I have here appears correct.  Try checking through HAL_InitTick, HAL_SYSTICK_Config, SysTick_Config etc.  If you can't find the problem then at least update the question to show where you call these functions and what your config is in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to set your TIM2 period to 499. It is zero-based just like the pre-scaler. From the manual:

> In upcounting mode, the counter counts from 0 to the auto-reload
> value(content of the TIMx_ARR register), then restarts from 0 and
> generates a counter overflow event.

You want to count from 0 to 499, then reset to zero.

This would explain why you are out by 2us per ms.